# Creating relations: #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql

I've tried to create a new table relation but I seem to have gotten an error for which I'm not sure why. The first relation (one to many) I made was last week and it works good, maybe I forgot the correct procedure since then?

Simple explanation:
I have three tables - events, music_styles, venues

So far, I correctly linked events and venues in the way that one venue can have multiple events linked to it. I tried making a new table that has rows for each musical style and an ID that would be used in table 'events' so that I can link each event to a musical style id.

However this is the error I got:

> SQL query:
>
> ALTER TABLE `events` ADD FOREIGN KEY ( `MUSIC_STYLE_ID` ) REFERENCES
>   `nightl7_complete`.`music_styles` ( `MUSIC_ID` ) ON DELETE NO ACTION
>   ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint
>
> fails (`nightl7_complete/#sql-2721_c0dcfd`, CONSTRAINT
>   `#sql-2721_c0dcfd_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`MUSIC_STYLE_ID`) REFERENCES
>   `music_styles` (`MUSIC_ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
>   Documentation Error ALTER TABLE `events` ADD FOREIGN KEY (
>   `MUSIC_STYLE_ID` ) REFERENCES `nightl7_complete`.`music_styles` (
>   `MUSIC_ID` ) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;

And this is the procedure I did :)

[image]

[I uploaded a full sized image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m00du.jpg)

Thanks everyone :)

---

Edit:

So I did this:

```
$query = 'SELECT e.* FROM events e '.
    'LEFT JOIN nightl7_complete.music_styles ms ON ms.ID = e.MUSIC_STYLE_ID'.
    'WHERE ms.id IS NULL';
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

and got this:

Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ms.id IS NULL' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you want to link `MUSIC_STYLE_ID` to `ID`, not `MUSIC_ID`?

Also, you need to either pre-populate `MUSIC_STYLE_ID` with valid ids from `music_styles`, or set them to null before creating the foreign key.

To verify this, try:

```
SELECT e.*
  FROM events e
  LEFT JOIN nightl7_complete.music_styles ms ON ms.ID = e.MUSIC_STYLE_ID
  WHERE ms.id IS NULL;
```

If that query returns any records, those are entries in `events` that don't contain corresponding records in `music_styles`

Comment: Hi Doug, I did prepopulate the music_styles table with 68 rows. I did as you suggested to use ID and I still have the same error. #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`nightl7_complete/#sql-2721_c1caae`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-2721_c1caae_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`MUSIC_STYLE_ID`) REFERENCES `music_styles` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Comment: so, for each row in `events`, the value in `MUSIC_STYLE_ID` is available in `music_styles.id`? I'll revise my question with a suggested query to check this...

Comment: I deleted column MUSIC_STYLE_ID, and since music_styles.ID is already indexed I thought I could use it as a foreign key?

Comment: Hmm, maybe I made a mistake somewhere?
EDIT: I will just update my main post