# mysql insert into database only if user exists in datatabase?

Tags: php, mysql

hi im looking for a way to implement a condition either in php or mysql that carry's out the below mysql query only if the 'from_user_id' exists in the database?

i have table called ptb_users that stores all the user id's, the other table that the below query inserts content into is ptb_wallposts.

users can write on other users walls, but before a user can write on a users wall/before the insert query runs i want the condition to cross reference with ptb_users to make sure the user sending the message/the from_user_id exists. so if user 1 is logged in and wants to send a message to user 2s wall then it first checks that the from_user_id matches the user_id in ptb_users.

so for instance i dont want people to sql inject data into the database by being able to have a from_user_id of 0, it must be matching with a user_id in the database or display and error message.

Can someone please advice me how i might do this. thanks.

my ptb_wallposts table looks like this

```
id   |     from_user_id   |  to_user_id  |  content

1               2                3            hello
```

my ptb_users table looks like this:

```
id   |     user_id   |  

1             2
```

mysql query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ptb_wallposts (id, from_user_id, to_user_id, content) VALUES (NULL, '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '".$profile_id."', '".$content."');";
            mysql_query($sql, $connection);
```

Comment: You can firstly `SELECT ... user` and in case you do not have a NULL value, do the `INSERT`.

Comment: First, make sure to create a foreign key for from_user_id, to_user_id to user's table, then to display a friendly message, you can do a select as zipser mentioned

Comment: how would i structure my select statement i have tried this: $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM ptb_users WHERE ptb_users.user_id=ptb_wallposts.from_user_id";
    if(!$sql) 

   $sql2 = "INSERT INTO ptb_wallposts (id, from_user_id, to_user_id, content) VALUES (NULL, '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '".$profile_id."', '".$content."');";
   mysql_query($sql, $connection);

Comment: This has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854274/insert-rows-only-when-id-from-another-table-exists and other previous posts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT id  FROM ptb_users WHERE user_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'"))){
        //your insert statement 
}

else{
        //not allowed 
}
```

I see you are using $_SESSION variable I think you don't need to check whether the user_id exists in database because $_SESSION variables can't be manipulated by end user.

Comment: would i be able to add to this to say AND WHERE ptb_wallposts.from_user_id is NOT NULL? so people can't hack it and add a user_id of 0?

Answer (score 1):

Use foreign keys and SQL does the job for you. First you need to add them like

```
ALTER TABLE `ptb_wallposts`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `users_wallposts_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`from_user_id`) REFERENCES `ptb_users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    ADD CONSTRAINT `users_wallposts_fk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`to_user_id`) REFERENCES `ptb_users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

And now if you want to insert an `id` that is not in `ptb_users` you'll get a SQL error.

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481476/when-to-use-on-update-cascade) for info on the meaning of `ON DELETE CASCADE`

Comment: #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ptb2013/#sql-22b9_26f4d4`, CONSTRAINT `users_wallposts_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`from_user_id`) REFERENCES `ptb_users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

Comment: Do you have invalid entries at the moment? ([Creating relations: #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274494/creating-relations-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-cons)